# Google Maps libraries 404

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api

I import Google Maps API since long time on my project with:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps-api-ssl.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places,geometry&amp;sensor=false&amp;language=fr" ></script>`

This script try to load 3 libraries:

```
  https://maps-api-ssl.google.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/21/9/intl/fr_ALL/main.js 
  https://maps-api-ssl.google.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/21/9/intl/fr_ALL/geometry.js
  https://maps-api-ssl.google.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/21/9/intl/fr_ALL/places.js
```

But all fail, and return 404

The same script without https is working, but the problem is just until 1 ou 2 days..

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps-api-ssl.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places,geometry&amp;sensor=false&amp;language=fr" ></script>`

juste call

```
  http://maps-api-ssl.google.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/21/9/intl/fr_ALL/main.js 
  http://maps-api-ssl.google.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/21/9/intl/fr_ALL/geometry.js
  http://maps-api-ssl.google.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/21/9/intl/fr_ALL/places.js
```

[image]

Have you an idea of why ?

Comment: If I attempt to get [`https://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/21/9/intl/fr_ALL/main.js`](https://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/21/9/intl/fr_ALL/main.js) it works.

Comment: I susspect language={{ getLanguage() }}, what is the getLanguage returns here?

Comment: In fact, the script not really call this url, but this one, don't know why:

https://maps-api-ssl.google.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/21/9/intl/fr_ALL/main.js

Comment: language is simply 'fr'

Comment: possible duplicate of [404 Not Found error for all the Google Maps API V3 libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31842389/404-not-found-error-for-all-the-google-maps-api-v3-libraries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue with the maps api on that url, though using the en_GB version. It was fine up until last night. I have fixed it by calling the url on the google api tutorial at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

So instead of:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps-api-ssl.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places,geometry&amp;sensor=false&amp;language=fr" ></script>
```

You could try:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places,geometry&amp;sensor=false&amp;language=fr" ></script>
```